# How to match move a green screen video with a static background

Tags: tracking

I am trying to figure out how to get a static background move with green screen footage. The problem that I am having is that the footage is with a moving camera. The actors are sitting at a table. I have tried after effects motion tracking with no luck. So, here I am in Blender trying to figure out the best way to start the process. Any tutorials or tips I should be starting at? Ive been working on this film for 2yrs and working on the green screen part itself for several months with no progress. If anyone can help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/lY8Ol2n4o4A) is the first part of a two part tutorial. It's the best short introduction to motion tracking in Blender that I know of.

Comment: Thank You so much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: If someone answered your question, consider accepting it by pressing the checkbox on the top left of the answer.